# jQuery Modal Dialog - I must be missing a simple thing

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php page that needs a modal confirmation.

When clicking "Please confirm" on the dialog, I want the page post to continue. How in the world can I accomplish this?

Here is my js code so far:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            buttons: {
                "Please confirm": function() {
                 // want to continue the post that was interrupted 
                 // by this dialog
                $("#account_mgr").submit();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                window.location = "/account_mgr#MySubscription";
                }
            }
        });

//  $('#btnSubscription').click(function() {
    $('#btnSubscription').live('click', function() {
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't POST at all to begin with. Return a true/false with your dialog, and only POST if true.

Comment: Ok, I see now that I missed your code that did exactly the same thing.  I take it that your code doesn't work?  Could you post the form tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the button otherwise posts a form, then just submit the form;

```
        buttons: {
            "Please confirm": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                $('#btnSubscription').parents('form').submit();
            },
            Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            window.location = "/account_mgr#MySubscription";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I think you are close. The form submits, and I see my post data, except for the button. :-/ I need the button value in my php code. My form tag: form action="http://local.spod-dev.com/account_mgr" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="center_form" name="account_mgr" id="account_mgr"> My button: <button name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubscription" value="MySubscription" type="submit" class="green"> Form is using jQuery tab. There are 4 tabs, each tab div has a button name="btnSubmit", but with a different id. jQuery tab works well with this. Maybe multiple buttons with same name is bad?

Comment: I find that I can see the button in the post data if I make the following change: $('#btnSubscription').live('submit', function() instead of $('#btnSubscription').live('click', function(). But then, the dialog does not pop up. :-/